# Can the super.save() method be used several times in a model?

Tags: django

In the `save` method of my Item model, I need the instance to be saved in the DB in order to compute a ranking according to some quantity:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):        

    super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    # get all the Item instances, order and get the ranking of the current instance

    self.ranking = ranking

    super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It seems to work, but I'd like to be sure to get no undesirable effects. Is that ok to do that?

Comment: You should back up your multiple calls to super() with unit tests :)

Comment: @Brandon, I'm not sure how that's relevant to the question?

Comment: Well, unit tests would demonstrate the affect, or lack of, any side effects as the result of multiple calls to super.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this will have any negative effects, but another approach would be just to update the ranking and not save the whole model. You can do that like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    Item.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(ranking=ranking)
```